# Lookup with concat followed by match, doesn't return the result of the latter

Tags: mongodb, lookup, concatenation

I'm new to MongoDB and I'm trying to perform aggregate of multiple collections in order to validate a HTTP request. Right now I need to lookup a collection, concat a value of the collection I've looked up with a given string and use the result of the concat on a match equals. The code below is what i currently have:

```
{
  from: "Patient",
  let: {
    subject: "$subject.reference"
  },
  pipeline: [
    {
      $project: {
        concatTest: {
          $concat: [
            "Patient/",
            "$id"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $eq: [
            "$concatTest",
            "$$subject"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  as: "result"
}
```

The problem:

The result array does not outputs the collection after filtering with match and instead outputs the results of the concat as shown:

```
result:Array
0:Object
_id:5d6d13175def3532dd905767
concatTest:"Patient/5d6d13175def3532dd905767"
```

I'm guessing this is a pretty simple problem of placing the right output, however I can't find a solution to it. Maybe i shouldn't be doing concat inside the pipeline? Or I completely misunderstood out the pipeline works?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ye, was just a simple problem of having the concat has part of the pipeline and not within the match. Solution was to write the match as follows:

```
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $eq: [
            "$$subject",
              {$concat:["Patient/","$id"]}
          ]
        }
      }
```

This way the concat is resolved into the match and not into the pipeline.